# Django: Select related over nested foreign keys

Tags: django, database, caching, many-to-many

I have:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass
class AList(models.Model):
    list_of_a= models.ManyToManyField(A)
    random_statistical_info=models.CharField()
class B(models.Model):
    a_list = models.ForeignKey(AList)
```

I am defining `AList` like this, as my code is going to define functions that make more sense, when used with lists of A, and not A. ie, meta-data stuff, etc.

Now, my question is, How can I use `select_related`/`prefetch_related` so that I can save all the `A` instances as well as `x` in `AList` when I run a filter query over `B`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following will work:

```
b_qs = B.objects.prefetch_related('a_list__list_of_a')
```

Now

```
for b in b_qs:
    x = b.a_list.list_of_a.all()
```

will result in three db queries:

Fetching table `B`, table `AList`, and table `A` using an `INNER JOIN` on the m2n table:

```
1 SELECT app_b.*
  FROM app_b

2 SELECT app_alist.*
  FROM app_alist 
  WHERE app_alist.id IN (1, 2, ...)  # fk values from 1

3 SELECT (app_alista.alist_id) AS _prefetch_related_val_alist_id, 
  app_a.*
  INNER JOIN app_alista ON app_a.id = app_alista.a_id 
  WHERE app_alista.alist_id IN (1, 2, ... )  # pk values from 2
```

Comment: Saved my day, but i want to know why prefetch is more efficient than select_related in that case